# Can't install sasquatch tool

Tags: file-format, python, decompress, binwalk

Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. I'm trying to install [sasquatch](https://github.com/devttys0/sasquatch) tool (which should apply patches to the standard unsquashfs utility), but got the issue, every time build process show error in one place:

```
./build.sh: 35: ./build.sh: cannot open ../patches/patch0.txt: No such file
```

Here is build [log](https://pastebin.com/raw/3sUrkTan). Please advice about this issue.